# wcf ServiceSecurityContext concurrency

Tags: wcf

I have a **WCF** service which uses a custom authentication and authorization manager.

Each time a client makes a call the authentication manager looks for a message header and uses the information to identify the user. The user gets created as an `IPrincipal` and placed into `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.AuthorizationContext.Properties["Principal"]`.

I noticed on subsequent calls, where the users is different, the old user info is in the `Current` context. My service is tagged as PerCall. I am stumped on why the context is not getting cleared for every call.

Or is `OperationContext` different lifetime from `SecurityContext`?

If so any ideas on how to achieve what I described above? Thanks for help.

Comment: What kind of binding are you using in your example??